# How to make the new window display in the center of the screen?

Tags: window, 22.04

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04LTS. When I open a new window, the new window will appear in the upper left corner of the screen. That's terrible. I'd like to know how to make the new window display in the center of the screen. I have downloaded the CCSM(CompizConfig Settings Manager) and changed the settings, but it doesn't work. HELP!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're running GNOME, try this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter center-new-windows true
```

If that doesn't work, try installing GNOME Tweaks using `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`, launching it, then going to "Windows" and enabling the "Center New Windows" option.

Comment: Thank you very much! I installed GNOME Tweaks and then finished the setting successfully!

Comment: Pleasure's all mine! Happy I could help! Have a blessed rest of your day (or night)!